# can vnc server detect change in dns settings

Tags: dns, vnc

i want to change the settings for dns server to use Google dns server, i have vnc server installed on my system for monitoring, can the vnc server detect the change of dns server settings change ?

Comment: This question might be better asked as: would ANY RUNNING APPLICATION detect a change of DNS servers while it is running? I.e., this is not in any way specific to `Xvnc`. [And the answer would appear to be "no"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125466/using-glibc-why-does-my-gethostbyname-fail-after-i-dhcp-has-changed-the-dns-ser/125486#125486), but I don't know for sure or if perhaps `Xvnc` might do something special. Incidentally, why do you care about `Xvnc` detecting the change? Just so that it logs correct hostnames when clients connect?

Comment: sites are blocked at work, so changing dns server to google seems to be the solution, now i do not want this change to be noticed to any1. hope you got my point

Comment: Sounds like you're asking the wrong question. It sounds like you want to know if sysadmins at your company will know (or care) that you have changed your DNS resolver. Nothing to do with VNC... Nothing to do with programming either.

Comment: yes could your right could you help me in that case